# Creates a button that when pressed, changes the text-TypeScript, React

Tags: html, css, node.js, typescript

I am new in this language and i couldn't find a solution.
this is my code:

```
{<a>Right now {order.status === 'full' ? 'x' : 'y'}</a>}
```

And I want to change the text to a button that when clicked will change the text of the button, and return to the previous text after another click, and so on

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe what your goal is in more detail? Also, what is `order`? How is that defined?

Comment: my goal is to create order system. and order have its all details of each order

Answer (score 0):

You should use the useState hook and update the text on the click but updateing the boolean state of the isFull hook.

You could also pass in the state from a parent object and emit the click event out to the parent  for state management between the button and other components.

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";
  import "./button.scss";

  const [isFull, setIsFull] = useState(false);

  function toggleStatus() {
    setIsFull(!isFull);
  }

    function Button() {
      return (
        <button
          type="button"
          className='button'
          onClick={() => toggleStatus()}
        >
          {isFull ? "x" : "y"}
        </button>
      );
    }
    
    export default Button;
```